# How to do javascript form submit in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am working in JavaScript, jQuery and MVC application.

```
document.forms['shipform'].submit();
```

Here I submit my form like this.
Totally I have three form in this page.
This is my form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("OrderShipments", "Shipments", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "shipform" })) // Creates <form>
{%>
    <input type="hidden" id="Hiddenid" name="orderId" />
    <input type="submit" value="book" style="display: none" />
<%} %>
```

It is not working in Chrome, but it works in Firefox.

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

If I use `forms[0]` which form would it take if I have three form in single page?

Comment: what is the error shown in Developer Console?

Comment: Could you please be more precise on what doesn't work? It doesn't submit or it submits all or it submits one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have will submit the form based on its name:

```
 document.forms['shipform'].submit();
                ^^^ form name not ID
```

If you want to submit the form by its ID then use:

```
 document.getElementById('shipform').submit();
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('#shipform').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can do this:

```
$('#shipform').submit();
```

Assuming that code outputs a form with `ID="shipform"`

```
<form id="shipform"></form>
```

- http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

You can "get" the form with `getElementById()`, then `submit()` it:

```
document.getElementById("shipform").submit();
```

This should send in your form.
(Assuming the `{ @id = "shipform" }` sets the `id` on your form to `"shipform"`)

If you use `forms[0]`, it should use the "first" form on your page, so the one that's loaded first, in your html.